# Azure function not returning result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-functions

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89WXgaY-NqY&t=) and I can see the correct result from the `console.log(result)` in the console, but when I make the GET request from postman, it returns nothing. Why is `send(200, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));` 
not working?

I also did a `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))` and it returns correctly the data correctly to the console. Just can't send it in response for some reason.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Post = require('./model/post');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {

  let currentPage = 1;
  context.log("process.env.CosmosDBConnectionString");
  context.log(process.env.CosmosDBConnectionString);

  MongoClient.connect(process.env.CosmosDBConnectionString, (err, client) => {

    let send = response(client, context);

    if (err) send(500, err.message);


    console.log("DBNAME: " + process.env.dbName);
    let db = client.db(process.env.dbName);

    let queryDate = Date.now();


    db.collection('listings').find({}) //test

      .toArray((err, result) => {
        console.log(result);
        if (err) send(500, err.message);
        send(200, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));

      });
  });




};

function response(client, context) {
  return function (status, body) {
    context.res = {
      status: status,
      body: body
    };

    client.close();
    context.done();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what "send" function does in this case, but I think if you just change it to the following should work:

```
db.collection('listings').find({}) //test
.toArray((err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
    if (err)
    {
        context.res = { status: 500, body: err.message }; 
    }
    else 
    {
        context.res = { status: 200, body: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)) }; 
    }
    context.done();
});
```

Comment: With your updated change, it's still returning blank. Updated code: https://pastebin.com/dnEGuhyH  The only thing on postman I see configured is content type as ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` There are no params set or anything. Also the console.log data says status 200

Comment: Another thing is if I do ```console.log(context.res)``` after else statement assignment it outputs the data there as well. Postman returns 200 too https://postimg.cc/r0H5QL98

Comment: try removing the async  from module.exports = async function (context, req) {

Comment: That was it! Postman works now. I thought I had to use async since the template uses it. Thanks! Also I tried the ```send(200...``` way I had it framed from my question that I learned from tutorial and that works too. I was wondering where that send function was coming from as well. I guess maybe it's built in to azure functions somehow?

Comment: in the docs there's context.res.send. Maybe it's a synthax sugar... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node

Comment: Do you know why I can't use ```.then``` . If I change ```.toArray``` to ```.then()```  it says it's not a function. That's how I had it originally. Is it not supported? Just wondering