# Azure Function displaying only error response not the result

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

request body is sent as an argument to the add user function which send back callback function two parameter status and res1. if user created then the status is 201 and another parameter is result. if user not created then status is 401 and another parameter is error. the problem is response is displayed only when the status is 401 or user did not created because of error.

```
index.js
    const insertUser = require('./db/insertUser')
    module.exports = async function (context, req) {
        insertUser.addUser(req.body,(status,res1)=>{
            context.res={
                status,
                body: res1
            };
            context.done();
        })
    }
    
    insertUser.js
    require('./dbconnect')
    const user = require('./utill/user')
    const addUser = (body,callback) =>{
        const User = new user(body)
        const value = User.save((error,result)=>{
            if(result){
                callback(201,result)
            }
            else{
                callback(401,error)
            }                     
            })
}
module.exports.addUser = addUser
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of writing complete `error` try using `err` and check, below is the example for your understanding

[image]

Then,
Check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60607007) for further details.

Also check [JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2) documentation for better understanding.